# Getting "closed from commit X" from Github API?

Tags: github-api

The Github API has a clear method for seeing whether a pull request has been closed or not. For example, [this pull request](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/issues/1535), has been closed, and we can determine that using [an API call](https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/).

However, some pull requests are "closed from a commit", e.g. [here](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/issues/1536). How can one use the Github API to determine whether a pull request is just "closed" or "closed from a commit"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is actually not of a pull request but rather an issue. You can see information about the closing of an issue through [GitHub's Issue Events API](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/events/).

[Example:](https://developer.github.com/v3/issues/events/#list-events-for-an-issue)

> ## List events for an issue
>
> `GET /repos/:owner/:repo/issues/:issue_number/events`
>
> ### Response
>
> ```
> Status: 200 OK
> Link: <https://api.github.com/resource?page=2>; rel="next",
>       <https://api.github.com/resource?page=5>; rel="last"
> X-RateLimit-Limit: 5000
> X-RateLimit-Remaining: 4999
> [
>   {
>     "id": 1,
>     "url": "https://api.github.com/repos/octocat/Hello-World/issues/events/1",
>     "actor": {
>       "login": "octocat",
>       "id": 1,
>       "avatar_url": "https://github.com/images/error/octocat_happy.gif",
>       "gravatar_id": "",
>       "url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat",
>       "html_url": "https://github.com/octocat",
>       "followers_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/followers",
>       "following_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/following{/other_user}",
>       "gists_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/gists{/gist_id}",
>       "starred_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/starred{/owner}{/repo}",
>       "subscriptions_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/subscriptions",
>       "organizations_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/orgs",
>       "repos_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/repos",
>       "events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/events{/privacy}",
>       "received_events_url": "https://api.github.com/users/octocat/received_events",
>       "type": "User",
>       "site_admin": false
>     },
>     "event": "closed",
>     "commit_id": "6dcb09b5b57875f334f61aebed695e2e4193db5e",
>     "created_at": "2011-04-14T16:00:49Z"
>   }
> ]
> ```

Notice the **`commit_id`** field in the response.